# Use Mailkit to validate input string is an email

Tags: asp.net-core, mailkit

I see that `MimeKit.MailboxAddress` has a `TryParse` method, can this be used to Validate that some string input is an email address using one if its overrides? The docs are pretty confusing and the `TryParse` alone parses `!realEmail!com"` just fine.

To be clear, I don't need to validate that an email actually exists, just that its a valid email. I would also like to avoid regex and just make sure the email is valid as MimeKit sees it... Do I have to create a fake message and try to add the address just to do this? seems excessive. System.Net.Mail would just through an exception for an invalid email, that was nice since I could just use a try/catch.

Answer (score 7):

MimeKit is designed to try and treat all input as valid as much as it realistically can.

What you want is my https://github.com/jstedfast/EmailValidation library.

Comment: ufff thanks for the answer, a whole seperate library seems heavy so I might just use regex but I will take a look.

Comment: You’ll never get a correct refer and that library is only 100 lines of code.

Comment: That should say regex, not refer (phone auto-correction)

Comment: Well I'd love to see it in a TryParse or some similar method in Mime or Mailkit someday but thats up to yourself and the community. Thanks for all your work on Mailkit and .net core!!

Comment: MimeKit 2.1.3 will have more ParserOptions to tweak the behavior of the address parser, but even with that, it's not designed to be as strict as the EmailValidation library is just due to the nature of broken email software that MimeKit has to be compatible with.

Answer (score 1):

maybe try this to throw an exception for an invalid email address:

```
internal static bool IsValid(string mail)
{
    try
    {
        // well known .Net style
        // var netMailAddress = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(mail);

        // Mailkit 3.4 style
        var kitMailAddress = new MimeKit.MailboxAddress(null, mail);
        return true;
    }
    catch
    { return false; }
}
```

and test `if (isValid(...)) {...}` without the "fake message".